# Separability of $X^{q^d}-X\in\mathbb F_q[X]$ for $d\in\mathbb N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

I know that I can verify that $f:=X^{q^d}-X\in\mathbb F_q$ and $f'$ (the formal derivative) are coprime in order to establish $f$'s separability. Is there an easier way, in particular one that does not use the formal derivative? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the argument with the formal derivative is the easiest way.